# Read List:The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized

Tags: c#, list, sharepoint

I'm trying to read a list in project online with a c# app
So here my code:

```
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(client.activeProfileUrl.ToString());
List announcementsList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("GetUrl");
CamlQuery query = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery(100);
ListItemCollection items = announcementsList.GetItems(query);
clientContext.Load(items);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
foreach (ListItem listItem in items)
{
    logUtil.writeLine("Title: " + listItem["Title"]);
}
```

So my client.activeprofile returns me the url of the environement where my user is connected (it's working well) but when I arrived at the line :`clientContext.ExecuteQuery();`

I get an error 401

Any idea of what I should do?

Thanks

Comment: What is `ClientContext`? And, you should do whatever the API does to authorise itself with the server.

Comment: Maybe ask this at the [sharepoint] site.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must set credentials for ClientContext.
Please see this link:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/connect-to-sharepoint-2013-online-using-csom-with-console-ap/
I think it will be what you want.

```
clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName,password);
```